# What happens if a UITableViewCell is not released?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, memory-management

What will happen if the autorelease is removed from cell creation in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    

STVCell *cell = (STVCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[STVCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will lead to a memory leak.

Because you call `alloc`, you are responsible for also calling `release` (or in this case `autorelease`).

The UITableView will automatically retain the cell and release its use of the cell at the appropriate time, but unless your code also releases the reference that it holds, the cell can never be deallocated.

Comment: There is no safe place to manually release it, which is why you need to use autorelease. You can't release it before you return it (because it would be deallocated before your caller gets a chance to see it), and once you've returned, there's no way for you to know when it's "safe" to call release. (Not to mention, where would you store the reference so you know what to release?) This situation is exactly what `autorelease` is designed for: when a method needs to return a reference to allocated storage and release it "soon". Use autorelease.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. And that's a bad thing: The cell will never be released and become a memory leak.